# Valgrind's error message

Tags: c, valgrind

I got "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" , and it is coming from function `process_server()`. I have tried to figure out where it is coming, but to no avail.

Message from `valgrind`.

> ==2468== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==2468==    at 0x402B3D: process_server (in /home/emeka/Desktop/dump/project/serverd)
> ==2468==    by 0x402DB3: main (in /home/emeka/Desktop/dump/project/serverd)
> ==2468==

```
#include "signal.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "arpa/inet.h"
#include "netdb.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "utility.h"
#include "route.c"
#include "tokenize.c"
#include "bridge.c"




#define PORT 1253
#define ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
#define START  "start"
#define  STOP  "stop"
#define LISTENQ 4

typedef struct sockaddr SA;
//#define INET6_ADDRSTRLEN 3000
requested_data *re_data;

int switch_ch;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;

int start_server(int port){
    int listenid;
    int optval=1;
    typedef struct sockaddr SA;
    if((listenid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        error_message("Error in startServer <Failed to create socket>");
    }
    if (setsockopt(listenid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                   (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int)) < 0)
            return -1;
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
    if(bind(listenid, (SA*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) {
        error_message("Error in startServer <Failed to bind socket>");
    }
    if(listen(listenid, LISTENQ) < 0) {
        error_message("Error in startServer <Failed to listen>");
    }


    return listenid;
}


void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

void process_server(int listenid){
    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int fd, read_size;
        const int buffer_size = 1000;
    char *client_message = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
        if(!client_message){
           printf("Not enough memory");
           abort();
         }
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
    char *gen, gen_int = 0, supplied_answer;
        while((fd = accept(listenid, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen))) {
        while((read_size = recv(fd, client_message, buffer_size, 0)) > 0) {
            printf("%s", client_message);
            re_data = router(client_message, read_size);
            printf("Method %s --url::%s=+++\n", re_data->method, re_data->url);
            switch_ch = 1;
            free(client_message);
            client_message = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer_size);
            if(!client_message){
                printf("Not enough memory");
                abort();
            }
            break;

        }
        printf("DE server: new connection from %s on "
                            "socket %d\n",
                            inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family,
                                get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr),
                                remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN),fd);
        str_query *rem_data;
        str_query *header_meta = re_data->meta_data;
         while(header_meta){
            if(strncasecmp(re_data->method, "PUT", 3) == 0){
                if(strncasecmp(re_data->url, "/answer", 7) == 0){
                    if(strlen(re_data->url) == 7){
                        if(strncasecmp(header_meta->req_name, "question", 8) == 0){

                            int res_int = parse_input(header_meta->req_value);

                            if(gen_int == res_int && supplied_answer == res_int){
                                send(fd, "HTTP status 200 OK" , 18, 0);
                            } else {
                                send(fd, "400 Bad Request" , 15, 0);
                            }

                            printf("\n Resulted from computation  of %s  result :: %d\n", header_meta->req_name, res_int);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if(switch_ch){
                if(strncasecmp(re_data->url, "/question" , 9) == 0){
                    if(strncasecmp(re_data->method, "GET", 3) == 0){
                        gen = pmain();
                        send(fd, gen, strlen(gen), 0);
                        gen_int = parse_input(gen);
                        switch_ch = 0;
                        printf("\n Resulted from generated computation  of %s  result :: %d\n", header_meta->req_name, gen_int);
                        free(gen);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(strncasecmp(header_meta->req_name, "answer", 8) == 0){
                supplied_answer = atoi(header_meta->req_value);

            }

            printf("\nname %s    value %s\n", header_meta->req_name, header_meta->req_value);
            rem_data = header_meta;
            header_meta = header_meta->next;
            free(rem_data->req_name);
                        free(rem_data->req_value);

            free(rem_data);

        }   
        if(!client_message){
           free(client_message);
        }   
        free(re_data);
        close(fd);
    }
    return;

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int port, pid, server_conn = 1;
    int internet_address_len = 15;
    char serAdd[internet_address_len];
    char strAction[7];
    if(argc == 1) {
        port = PORT;
        strcpy(serAdd, ADDRESS);
    } else if(argc == 2){
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        strcpy(serAdd, ADDRESS);
    } else if(argc == 3) {
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        int n = strlen(argv[2]);
        strncpy(serAdd, argv[2], n);
        if(n >= internet_address_len){
            error_message("Internet address is incorrect");
        }
        serAdd[n] = '\0';
    }
    printf("\n\tDE is a basic server built to carry out simple things\n"
            "\t-----    -----\n"
            "\t|    |   |\n"
            "\t|    |   -----\n"
            "\t|    |   |\n"
            "\t-----    -----\n"
           "\tMethods implemented [Get & Put]\n"
           "\tTo start type start\n"
            "\tTo stop type stop\nDE]");
    scanf("%s", strAction);
    if (strcmp(strAction, START) == 0){
        printf("Server %sed\n", START);
        int listenid = start_server(port);
        printf("listen on port %d & listening is %d\nDE]", port,listenid);
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
        while(server_conn) {
            pid =fork();
            if(pid == 0) {
                process_server(listenid);
                break;              
            }
            scanf("%s", strAction);
            if (strcmp(strAction, STOP) == 0) {
                close(listenid);
                return 0;
            }

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Compile your code with debugging symbols enabled so that valgrind will give code line numbers in its output. That will greatly assist others (and you) in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Please indent your code in a more orthodox style, too.  It may be that you have a mixture of tabs and blanks; avoid that for code posted to SO.  Use blanks only.  You may need to detab your file.  One way on Unix-like systems is `pr -e8 -l1 -t input.c > output.detabbed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thanks. I just learnt something new. I have solved this issue, I noticed that if in my list next pointer is accessed and it has no memory created for it , then the above named error would be triggered. I have learnt to always assign NULL to such.

Comment: The memory allocated by `malloc()` has indeterminate contents.  This is normally fine; you're about to write to every member of the structure.  If you're not, it is usually better to use `calloc()` which zeroes the allocated memory for you — all bytes zero.  This is at least determinate.  It is wasteful to use `calloc()`, though, if you're going to overwrite everything (but it protects you against changes — additions — to the structure that you're allocating, and you may decide the future-proofing is sufficiently beneficial to outweigh the not usually very significant cost).